mypy and variance on function returning a list of subclasses based on input parameter
I'm trying to annotate my code properly. Here's an example snippet to recreate my issue:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar


class Shape(BaseModel):
   name: str


class Circle(Shape):
   diameter: float


class Square(Shape):
   side: float


class Triangle(Shape):
   base: float
   height: float


T = TypeVar("T")


def generate_shapes(shapes: list[type[T]]) -> list[T]:
   generated_shapes = []
   for shape in shapes:
       if shape == Circle:
           generated_shapes.append(Circle(name=shape.__name__, diameter=10))
       elif shape == Square:
           generated_shapes.append(Square(name=shape.__name__, side=10))
       elif shape == Triangle:
           generated_shapes.append(Triangle(name=shape.__name__, base=10, height=10))
   return generated_shapes


if __name__ == "__main__":
   result = generate_shapes([Circle, Triangle])


Practically the code looks fine, however mypy complains. In particular the error I'm trying to understand is:

Argument 1 to "generate_shapes" has incompatible type
"list[ModelMetaclass]"; expected "list[type[Never]]"

My objective would be to be able to infer the output list type from the input. It looks like that using this annotation vscode is able to understand it:


My basic understanding is that mypy complains because lists are mutable and cannot be covariant. So I'm afraid there isn't a way out for what I'm trying to achieve (vscode inferring + mypy happy)?

Part of the problem is that generated_shapes has an inferred type of list[Circle] following the loop, simply because the first line of code that tries to append to it appends a Circle. It's type is never (directly) related to the type of shapes.

The pop-up hint for [Circle, Triangle] looks like something that Pyright, not mypy, infers. (Pyright, IIRC, infers too-specific types for things like this.)

Your function isn't really generic. Effectively, it expects a list of Shape classes and returns a list of Shapes. There's no real reason to allow a more general list as an argument. If the caller somehow has a list like [Circle, Triangle, 1, Square], they can be responsible for removing non-Shape-subclass elements first.
Further, the intially inferred type for generated_shapes is list[Any], which gets narrowed to list[Circle] by the first attempt to append anything to the list. If your function isn't generic, you can be explicit about the type of generated_shapes up front. (mypy doesn't go so far as to infer the type of generated_shapes from the declared return type of the function.)
def generate_shapes(shapes: list[type[Shape]]) -> list[Shape]:
   generated_shapes: list[Shape] = []
   for shape in shapes:
       if shape == Circle:
           generated_shapes.append(Circle(name=shape.__name__, diameter=10))
       elif shape == Square:
           generated_shapes.append(Square(name=shape.__name__, side=10))
       elif shape == Triangle:
           generated_shapes.append(Triangle(name=shape.__name__, base=10, height=10))
   return generated_shapes


I see what you mean, thanks. So in this example there is no point to bound T to Shape either? My initial thought was to use T in order to narrow down the union of possible shapes since in theory it should know what T is based on the input. But I see where the problem is if mypy doesn't go as far as inferring the type from the declaration.

Unless your goal is to accept a homogenous list, type[Shape] is both the least and the most specific type of list element you accept. (And a homogenous list like [Circle, Circle, Circle] would really be better represented as an integer and a type, like 3, Circle to generate a list of 3 instances of Circle.)

A bit more on what I found out playing around with the example snippet, mypy complains only when Shape inherits from BaseModel. So it's sort of related to pydantic too
